# Maven build excludes some .xml files from WEB-INF folder

Tags: java, xml, spring, maven, war

My WEB-INF folder contains 4 files and 1 directory:

```
drwxr-xr-x  238B Aug 18 16:53 .
drwxr-xr-x  136B Aug 14 13:23 ..
-rw-r--r--  302B Aug 14 13:23 applicationContext.xml
-rw-r--r--  302B Aug 14 13:23 dispatcher-servlet.xml
-rw-r--r--  1.1K Aug 18 16:53 spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml
drwxr-xr-x  102B Aug 18 16:52 view
-rw-r--r--  2.2K Aug 18 16:53 web.xml
```

Maven is configured to build war package. Here is a part of pom.xml:

```
    ...
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    ...
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <webXml>webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    ...
```

But when I pack the code for uploading to Tomcat:

```
mvn clean compile war:exploded
```

Only the web.xml file left in the folder:

```
$ pwd
spring-learning/target/1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF

$ ls -alh
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 170B Aug 18 17:08 .
drwxr-xr-x 136B Aug 18 17:08 ..
drwxr-xr-x 170B Aug 18 17:08 classes
drwxr-xr-x 340B Aug 18 17:08 lib
-rw-r--r-- 2.2K Aug 18 16:53 web.xml
```

I took that web.xml from an udemy course and it contains references to these additional .xml files, which are of course then failed to load on Tomcat.

web.xml:

```
...
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 10+ hours of desperate googling I finally noticed that Windows-type backslashes in the pom.xml file. Be aware copying path strings from the Internet!